# How to remap <Ctrl-Home> to go to first line in file?

Tags: vim

How to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to go to first line in file? I tried the following command, but it doesn't work (environment is xterm in KDE). Vim recognises the Home key and goes to beginning of line, but looks like it doesn't recognized <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> combo.

```
noremap <Ctrl-Home> gg
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Vim does not know `<Ctrl-` modifier. It calls it `<C-`. Try

   ```
   inoremap <C-Home> gg
   ```
2. If that does not help, then see whether there is some difference between what vim shows when you press `<C-v><C-home>` and `<C-v><Home>`, post both results here. If there is no difference, then it maybe is not possible.

Comment: Both `<C-v><C-home>` and `<C-v><Home>` give same output as below (ie it doesnt look like it is recognising <C-Home>, only <Home> 

  output - ^[[1~

Comment: @rrp try konsole: yakuake (which is based on konsole) gives `^[[1~` for `<Home>` and `^[[1;5H` for `<C-Home>`.

Comment: Urxvt also does distinguish: `^[[1~` and `^[[7^`.

Comment: Forget about it: I installed xterm and it does distinguish between `<Home>` and `<C-Home>`:  `^[[H` and `^[[5H`. Problem is with your installation. Post somewhere output of `xrdb -query | grep ^xterm`.

Comment: This is the output, though it doesnt look like it is related to any keybindings.

xrdb -query | grep ^xterm    
 
xterm*background:       #ffffff.
xterm*foreground:       #000000.
xterm.SimpleMenu*background:    #dcdcdc.
xterm.SimpleMenu*foreground:    #000000.

Comment: @rrp Is this all output? I have also things like `xterm*modifyCursorKeys: 0///
xterm*modifyFunctionKeys:       0///
xterm*modifyOtherKeys:  0` (/// replaces newline). Try `echo -e 'xterm*modifyOtherKeys: 0\nxterm*modifyFunctionKeys: 0\nxterm*modifyCursorKeys: 0' | xrdb -merge -`

Comment: After above cmds my xrdb -query gives 3 additional lines  \\\
xterm*modifyCursorKeys: 0 \\\
xterm*modifyFunctionKeys:       0 \\\
xterm*modifyOtherKeys:  0 \\\

But still no luck with  `noremap <C-Home>  gg`
(\\\ means newline)

Comment: @rrp 0. Have you restarted xterm after using xrdb? 1. Before doing `noremap` check `<C-v><C-Home>` and `<C-v><Home>`. Maybe you need to tell vim that some particular sequence is `<C-Home>`. 2. If `<Home>` and `<C-Home>` still does not differ, then what distro is this? Cannot help you without trying to reproduce this on virtual machine. 3. Does `<C-Home>` differ from `<Home>` in konsole?

Comment: 1. yes restarted xterm . `<C-v><C-Home>` and `<C-v><Home>` are still same.  2. Distro is setup by my company,  so not really sure. Mostly it looks some kind of custom distro. 3. Konsole same result as xterm  4. info - 'kate' text editor in my KDE is able to recognise <C-Home> easily. So issue is with only xterm/konsole. 5. I used `set termcap` command in vim and saw this  combo `<C-Home>   ^[05H`. I used `set <C-Home>=^[05H` in vim and used map cmd . But still no difference. (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/term.html)

Comment: @rrp My xterm also has `xterm*combiningChars:   4 ///
xterm*ctrlFKeys:        12` xrdb entries. I do not think that setting this will work (at least, blanking xrdb changed nothing in `...Home>` behavior), but try setting them. What does `setxkbmap -print` show?

Comment: @ZyX  
1. set the new xterm options also. No difference. 
2. `setxkbmap -print` shows XKB extension not present on hostname:1.0

Comment: @rrp Sorry, but I do not know what to do then.