# Move to the beginning of line while in Insert mode

Tags: vim

I know that I can use either:

1. <kbd>Home</kbd> in insert mode
2. <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to exit insert mode and enter it again, effectively going to the beginning of line.

But neither satisfies me. In first case I have  to tilt my head to hit <kbd>Home</kbd>, because I can't blindly hit it. In second case my left arm has to leave the home row to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, which is annoying too.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use 0 to move to the beginning of the line, but that's not in insert mode.

Comment: And if you find Esc to be to far as well, you can use Ctrl-[ instead :)

Comment: Or better, Ctrl-C works like Esc. Or even better, map Caps Lock to Esc.

Comment: @manku you didn't so much answer his question as you did not answer his question =P

Comment: remap esc to jj you need to shift between modes a lot in vim

Comment: What is the “Home” key...?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> whilst in insert mode puts you in command mode for one key press only. Therefore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> should accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: You could accomplish the same thing by hitting Ctrl+c, I or Ctrl+[, I. Ctrl+c is functionally similar to ESC and Ctrl+[ is equivalent to ESC.

Comment: Or `Ctrl-o` followed by `0` (slightly more efficient than `Ctrl-o` followed by `Shift-I`), as you will be back in insert mode automatically. In some cases,  `Ctrl-o` followed by `^` might be better (to move to the first non-whitespace character of the line).

Comment: you can use Alt-A or Alt-I while in insert mode if your alt key sends escape (can be configured in iTerm2)

Comment: `<C-O>` is not the same as `<C-[>` or `<Esc>` although they may look alike. The difference is an edit with a regular escape + <something to get you into insert mode again> leaves you with two edits, while <C-O> leaves you with one. This can help you maintain a cleaner undo history, and be able to reuse that insert for pasting. Some vim'ers will argue that you should pay attention to stuff like that.

Comment: I don't understand. Both on Linux and Mac OSX, ctrl + O doesn't work. But if I press ESCAPE key, it goes to command mode and then shift + I works.

Answer (score 59):

You could enter insert mode using `I` (capital i).

It will put the cursor at the beginning of the line.

Similarly you can use `A` to add something at the end of the line.

Though, it does not really solve the problem of moving while already being in Insert mode.

I have just checked help on Insert mode, there is no key combination in insert mode to move at the beginning of the line.

Other idea :
Remap a new command only in insert mode

`inoremap <C-i> <Home>`

Comment: T. <kbd>I</kbd> works fine, but I'm seeking the solution to move to the beginning of line while already being in insert mode.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly, but provides functionality that probably preempts the questions for most people.

Answer (score 25):

I've got Ctrl+a and Ctrl+e mapped to beginning and end of line, respectively. This matches the behavior of most bash command lines. Works well for me.

```
inoremap <C-e> <Esc>A
inoremap <C-a> <Esc>I
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken these are the keybindings for most other editors too. I'm going to add these to my vimrc file.

Comment: These are usual Emacs behaviours. Most browsers also support these in various types of text fields. I don't think this is a bad idea, but here's what you are missing out on: `<C-e>` copies/writes the character under the cursor (`<C-y>` for over cursor), `<C-a>` insert's whatever's in your .-register (dot-register). That register gets filled with whatever you just typed in, when you leave insert mode (even when using Ctrl-c (which you for many reason should not get used to)).

Comment: @Jonathan Cutrell         How do you go to the beginning of new line.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MacOS Terminal go to Preferences...>Settings>Keyboard and map the end key to Ctrl-O$ (it is displayed as \017$) and then use fn+left to simulate the end key. Do the same for the home key. Escape sequence \033[H also works for home.

Comment: fn-Left and fn-Right worked by default for me in vim on mac terminal

Answer (score 1):

Your best course of action is to remap the action to a different key (see [How to remap <Ctrl-Home> to go to first line in file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503252/how-to-remap-ctrl-home-to-go-to-first-line-in-file) for ideas)

I'd think of how often I use this "feature" and map it to a keystroke accordinly

Answer (score 0):

You can map the keys to this:

```
inoremap II <Esc>I
```

ref: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Quick_command_in_insert_mode

Comment: Unless you plan to mention WWII a lot :).

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut that has worked for me (both muscle memory and intuitiveness) is to map `__` (which is a double `_`) to "insert at start of current line".

Rationale:

- `_` already goes to the start of line
- in vim, doubling anything is a very common way of doing that "to this line"
- double `_` doesn't conflict with any motions (you're already at the start of line)
- your hand is already in the right place if you went to the beginning of the line and now want to insert.

vimscript:

```
"insert at start of current line by typing in __ (two underscores)
function DoubleUnderscore()
    if v:count == 0 && getcurpos()[2] == 1
        :silent call feedkeys('I', 'n')
    else
        :silent call feedkeys('^', v:count + 'n')
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> _ :call DoubleUnderscore()<CR>
```

It's this complicated because the easy alternative `nnoremap __ _I` causes vim to delay on pressing `_` to distinguish between `_` and `__`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ctrl+o then 0
     |      |
  letter  number
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this command to go to end of line without leaving insert mode

```
inoremap jl <esc><S-a>
```

Similarly to go to beginning of line will be:

```
inoremap jl <esc><S-i>
```