# Move to the beginning of New Line - VIM

Tags: vim

while in insert mode in vim how do i move to a new line correctly indented.

In many editors this action would be `CTRL+ENTER`

There is a similar stackoverflow question here however this answer takes you back to the start of the current line [SO start of current line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545137/461887)

So assuming this is my code, my cursor is just at the **T** in POST and i want to go to the start of the next line or next line with correct indentation if its a function(using snippets for function so now great concern).

@app.route('/add', method=['POST **|** '])

**expected result**

```
@app.route('/add', method=['POST'])
|
```

Comment: I would use `<esc>o`

Comment: esc o works; however, he specified that he'd like the new line correctly indented.

Comment: that works pretty well, on a line like that because the first line is correct, if it were a function though would be wrong. since I have ESC bound to jk, jk o is fairly efficient.

Comment: @FDinoff        actually if the line is already indented 'o' does take you to the correctly indented level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `<esc>o`. Assuming you have `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc `o` will automatically go to the correct indent level.

Answer (score 1):

Search for indentation and map to some keys, so you cannot search for every time.

```
/^^I
```

`^I` is tab